# how do I use a excel function inside the vba editor

Tags: excel, vba, function

I want to write a Excel function like this. It is an extension of the Dec2Bin function

```
Public Function Dec2BinEx(x As Long)
  Dec2BinEx = dec2bin(x) + 10
End Function
```

But I am getting an error when trying to use it. How do I call a excel function inside the visual basic editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you call Excel functions with `Application.WorksheetFunction.SomeFunctionName`. However, `Dec2Bin` is special, as it is an Add-In function, and not a pure Excel function. Hence, `Application.WorksheetFunction` does not work here. Instead, you have to make the functions of the add-in available to your code. To do so, follow these steps

- In Excel, menu Tools/Add-Ins, make
  sure that the add-in `Analysis
  ToolPak - VBA` is imported.
- Then, set a reference to this add-in
  in your code: in the VBA editor, menu
  Tools/References, add a reference to
  `atpvbaen.xls`.

Then, your original code, as posted in your quesiton should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I am also trying to call the Mod() function inside. Is there anything that needs to be referenced to support the Mod function in the VBA code

Comment: @Karthick: in VBA, there exists a Mod operator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164528%28office.10%29.aspx) that you can use. Instead of the worksheet function `=Mod(10,3)`, you write `10 Mod 3` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You will first of all have to create a module eg from menu select **Insert->Module**. Then inside this module create a function named **main**. This function is run by default when code is run. Now inside this function call your own function like this:

```
Sub main()
    Call Dec2BinEx(your_value_here)
End Sub

Public Function Dec2BinEx(x As Long)
    Dec2BinEx = dec2bin(x) + 10
End Function
```

Having done that, make sure that you have the reference to **dec2bin** function or if you create that too. Thanks

Comment: Sarfraz,
for an Excel user-defined function to be called from a worksheet you don't need a MAIN sub.

Comment: @Charles: thanks for letting me know about that, it has been long time since i have stopped working on this. Thanks